# Is there a general way to calculate the fundamental group of a quotient space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

Suppose $X$ is a path-connected topological space, and $A$ is a path-connected subset of $X$.  My question is, is there a way to calculate the fundamental group of the quotient space $X / A$ in terms of the fundamental groups of $X$ or $A$?

If there isn't a method in all cases, can you at least do it if $A$ has some special property?

Comment: If the inclusion $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration then you get a cofibration sequence $A\xrightarrow{i} X\rightarrow X/A$. You can use homology to study the connectivity of the map $i$, and in special cases says things about the low-dimensional homotopy groups of $X/A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that one can say anything about $X/A$. Consider $X = D^2 \vee S^1$ and $A_1$ = boundary of $D^2$, $A_2$ = second component of $D^2 \vee S^1$. Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are homeomorphic. They are nicely embedded into $X$. In fact they are subpolyhedra, hence the inclusions $A_i \to X$ are cofibrations. But $X/A_1 \approx S^2 \vee S^1$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $X/A_2 \approx D^2$ has fundamental group $0$.